# C equivalent to applescript "tell X to open Y"

Tags: c, applescript, tell

Does anybody have a C library function that does the equivalent of AppleScript "Tell application X to open Y"?  I'm not using cocoa, just plain old C, and ideally I would like to be able to do this from a commandl ine application that has no GUI interface.

This doesn't have to be fancy, it would be all right if I don't even wait for the success-or-failure response. Just needs to send the right Apple event.

Answer (score 0):

I think by far the simplest solution would be to issue a system call to the `osascript` command line utility.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  system("osascript -e 'tell application \"X\" to open POSIX file \"/path/to/Y\"'");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ugh, no. If you're going to use another process to open files in other apps, use `open`. And only use `system()` if executing a _hardcoded_ shell script (which probably isn't what the OP wants), otherwise use `fork()` and `exec*()`.

Comment: @foo Would you care to explain *why* you disapprove of this answer please? And why your alternative is better? Then we can all learn. Thank you.

Comment: Because it's poor practice that can easily encourage less experienced coders to create insecure, unsafe code. Using AppleScript via `osascript` is needless complexity as the `open` tool is already provided for exactly this task. Using `system()` is bad practice as it's almost certain the OP wants to supply the app and/or file name at runtime – and assembling and executing arbitrary code via string munging is a recipe for disaster if OP doesn't fully sanitize its inputs. (See also: every code injection attack ever.) `execv()` allows parameters to be passed directly so avoids this risk entirely.

Answer (score 0):

OP's kinda creating a rod for his own back here, as except for CoreFoundation most OS X-specific C APIs  are now legacy/deprecated. Used to be you could call LaunchServices' `LSOpenApplication()`, but that got deprecated in 10.10.

If `NSWorkspace` isn't an option then use [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) via `fork()` and `execv()`, which allows arguments to be passed directly.

Comment: Please expand the abbreviation "OP".  I know OS for operating system, but what's OP?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful thoughts, they really got me pointed in the right direction. Here's the synthesis of these answers that seems to be working well for me, code that assumes that the path and the filename will be variable:

```
char wdname[1000], obuf[1000];
const char* filename = "WavySwirl.stl";

getwd(wdname);
sprintf(obuf, "open %s/%s", wdname, filename);
system(obuf);
```

Comment: Sigh… and what did I just say about never string-munging unsanitized inputs? Much of C's stdlib is shockingly unsafe by design; hence the First Two Rules of C Programming: Assume Nothing, and Never Trust Anything. Otherwise C will bend you over a barrel and make you squeal like a piggie. e.g. Consider what happens if `filename` happens to be `"WavySwirl.stl; rm -rf /"` (and [**no, don't ever run that**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rm+-rf+%2F)). This is why I said to use `fork`+`execv`, because `execv` takes an array of C strings to pass as `argv`, so is *safe by default*.

Comment: Yes, if I were considering running this program on a server, I would be more careful. I'm well aware that people will send all kinds of nefarious things in your input. But on a personal computer that is not a server? If the bad guy could have gotten access to run my application, he also could have gotten access to run the same command in a shell, right?

Comment: Your unsafe code is just as susceptible to **accidental breakage** as deliberate subversion. The 'malicious' example is just to demonstrate just how potentially damaging your badly written code is. Any app or file name that happens to contain an apostrophe, double quote, or any other "special" shell character will break it too. If you're *lucky*, it'll only cause bash to throw an error and refuse to execute your malformed code. If you're unlucky and it does run, it could have any number of unintended/unwanted results. TL;DR: 1. **NEVER execute unsanitized inputs.** 2. **Don't debate, FIX.**